# Is there any way to do something, in order to ContentChildren could find components that are inside parent's <ng-content></ng-content>?

Tags: angular, ng-content

I have some components from third-party library, that work fine, when use next way:

```html
<lib>
  <lib-inner [text]="'111'"></lib-inner>
  <lib-inner [text]="'222'"></lib-inner>
</lib>
```

Simplified imitation of 'lib' and 'lib-inner' components code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "lib",
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngFor="let c of allInner;">
      <button>{{ c.text }}</button>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class LibComponent {
  @ContentChildren(LibInnerComponent) allInner: QueryList<LibInnerComponent>;
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: "lib-inner",
  template: ``
})
export class LibInnerComponent {
  @Input() text: string;
}
```

I want to create wrapper component:

```html
<wrapper-for-lib>
  <lib-inner [text]="'aaa'"></lib-inner>
  <lib-inner [text]="'bbb'"></lib-inner>
</wrapper-for-lib>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: "wrapper-for-lib",
  template: `
    <lib>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <lib-inner [text]="'default'"></lib-inner>
    </lib>
  `
})
export class WrapperForLibComponent {}
```

When we use this 'wrapper-for-lib' component, we see only 'default' button, but don't see buttons 'aaa' and 'bbb'.

'lib' component's ContentChildren() don't find 'lib-inner' components that are in ng-content,

Is there any way to solve this?

Notice, I can't change code of 'lib' and 'lib-inner', because they imitate case for real third-party library components, which I can't change.

[workable example with above code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-toolbar-ng-conent-imitation?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/app.component.ts)

[example for same case and real library component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-toolbar-ng-content?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: try add "descendants:true: `@ContentChildren(LibInnerComponent,{descendants:true})`, see the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren

Comment: Thanks, I am aware about this property, but it doesn't work for this case, and also I can't change @ContentChildren, because it's imitation of code of third-party library that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the lib-inner components from your wrapper and loop them in your template.

```
Component({
    selector: "wrapper-for-lib",
    template: `
    <lib>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let inner of libInners">
            <lib-inner [text]="inner.text"></lib-inner>
        </ng-container>
    </lib>
`
})
export class WrapperForLibComponent {
    @ContentChildren(LibInnerComponent) libInners: QueryList<LibInnerComponent>;
  }
```

Comment: Simple and good idea, it works. And I think it's pretty good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is lib-inner is rendering empty. Try render some content, and add ng-content to lib component:

lib-inner.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "lib-inner",
  template: `<button>{{text }}</button>`
})
export class LibInnerComponent {
  @Input() text: string;
}
```

lib.component.ts

```
import { Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "lib",
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class LibComponent {

}
```

wrapper-for-lib.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "wrapper-for-lib",
  template: `
    <lib>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <lib-inner [text]="'default'"></lib-inner>
    </lib>
  `
})
export class WrapperForLibComponent {}
```

EDIT: See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-toolbar-ng-conent-imitation-fazqq6?file=app%2Fwrapper-for-lib.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer, but
 firstly I don't see difference with your propose - ContentChildren in 'lib' component still find only one component ('default'),
 secondly I can't change code of 'lib' and 'lib-inner', because they imitate case for real third-party library.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, the code was not saved. I updated, see Edit. OK, I understand, you can't change 'lib' or 'lib-inner', but right now lib-inner renders nothing, I will try some workaround.